On the statement and proof that transitive models make the Axiom of Extensionality true
I have been trying to understand the proof in this post that transitive models make the Axiom of Extensionality true. $\def\limplies{\longrightarrow} \def\liff{\longleftrightarrow}$ Here is my attempt at making the statement and argument a bit more formal:

Definition: let $S$ be an arbitrary set. We define $S$-extensionality as
$$(x\neq y) \limplies \exists z \Big\{(z\in S)\land \Big[(z\in x\setminus y)\lor (z\in y\setminus x)\Big]\Big\}
$$
and define $S$-universality as
$$\forall x (x\in S)$$
With this in mind, I think the result and argument are as follows:
Result(?): let $V$ be such that $V$-extensionality and universality hold. If $M$ is transitive, then $M$-extensionality holds.
\begin{split}
1. \ \ \ \ &  x,y\in M \land (x\ne y) && \ \ \ \ \text{ assumption} \\
2. \ \ \ \ &  x,y\in V && \ \ \ \ \text{ by $V$-universality} \\
3. \ \ \ \ &  \exists z\Big\{(z\in V) \land \Big[(z\in x\setminus y) \lor (z\in y\setminus x)\Big]\Big\} && \ \ \ \ \text{ by $V$-extensionality} \\
4. \ \ \ \ &  \exists z\Big\{(z\in M) \land \Big[(z\in x\setminus y) \lor (z\in y\setminus x)\Big]\Big\} && \ \ \ \ \text{ by transitivity of $M$} \\
\end{split}

Question 1: am I correctly interpreting the post?
Question 2: it seems to me that $S$-extensionality is equivalent to
$$\forall z \Big\{(z\notin S)\lor \Big[(z\in x)\liff (z\in y)\Big]\Big\}\limplies (x=y)$$
which states that $x=y$ whenever these lie outisde of $S$. This seems intuitively wrong for any set $S\neq V$.

Not clear... the last formula says that $x=y$ if the two sets has the same elements wrt the sets in S. Thus, Extensionality "restricted" to S holds.

@MauroALLEGRANZA Well, yes, but suppose $x,y\notin S$, then we would conclude $x=y$, which could be false.

The problem, I think, is you're forgetting to bound the quantifer for the $x$ and $y$ variables. $S$-extensionality (i.e. extensionality relativized to $S$) should say $$ \forall x,y\in S(\forall z\in S(z\in x\leftrightarrow z\in y)\to x=y).$$ So, in answer to your second question, it doesn't say anything about the case where $x$ or $y$ are not in $S.$
You seem to be assuming this bounded quantification in your proof, though... otherwise why would you be allowed to assume $x,y\in M$ at the beginning? The fact that $x,y\in M$ is used in the justification of step 4, since we need $x,y \in M$ to conclude from transitivity of $M$ that $z\in M$ whenever $z\in x$ or $z\in y.$
